# Inserting empty rows into table due to 'duplicate items'

Tags: qt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I have a table view that requires the same information on multiple rows however these rows keep appearing empty and the same log message appears

```
'Ignoring duplicate insertion of item'
```

Basically I iterate over a model setup to contain all information and take the value at each index to populate another model attached to the table.
I tried to assign each index into a variable each time the loop iterates (which seems like overkill)

```
QString var1, var2, var3;
for ( int row = 0; row < m_infoModel->rowCount(); ++row )
        {
            item = new QStandardItem;
            var1 = m_infoModel->data( m_infoModel->index( row, 0 ) ).toString();
            item->setText( var1 );
            m_displayModel->setItem( row, 1, item );

            item = new QStandardItem;
            var2 = m_infoModel->data( m_infoModel->index( row, 1 ) ).toString();
            item->setText( var2 );
            m_displayModel->setItem( row, 2, item );

            item = new QStandardItem;
            var3 = m_infoModel->data( m_infoModel->index( row, 2 ) ).toString();
            item->setText( var3 );
            m_displayModel->setItem( row, 3, item );
        }
```

Is there a correct/more efficient way of getting around this 'duplicate insertion' or am I looking at it the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: If you need two tables show the same data, just use the same model for both table views. Of I misunderstand something?

Comment: No it's the same table that I need to insert data from the same model.. :/ But I have rows which contain the same column values for example Row 1 - 1, Bla, SameStuff, Row 2 - 1, Bla(something different), SameStuff. Hope that makes sense

Comment: I've check qt code. This warring is printed when adding item which already has parent. So your have shown code which doesn't generate this warning.
Additionally this is not a full content of warning so show full version.

Comment: `QStandardItem::insertRows: Ignoring duplicate insertion of item 0x29a9850`

Comment: 4 years later I stumble upon the same issue, on Python. Did you found any fix?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this as I did. The clue is in Marek R's answer about parents. When you insert an item into a model and that item is already in another model it will cause this issue.
To fix it you need to make a new QStandardItem encapsulating the data from the existing QStandardItem.

Hopefully how I fixed it makes sense.

This was my code experiencing the same issue (copying new rows of text from m_logModel to m_model):

```
for (int i = first; i <= last; i++)
{
    QList<QStandardItem*> nextRow;
    for (int j = 0; j < m_logModel->columnCount(); j++)
    {
        nextRow << m_logModel->item(i, j);
    }
    m_model->appendRow(nextRow);
}
```

This changed code makes it work as expected:

```
for (int i = first; i <= last; i++)
{
    QList<QStandardItem*> nextRow;
    for (int j = 0; j < m_logModel->columnCount(); j++)
    {
        nextRow << new QStandardItem(m_logModel->item(i, j)->text());
    }
    m_model->appendRow(nextRow);
}
```

Hopefully this will help the next person who finds this issue.